# Error: method 'value' of object 'range' failed - input dynamic formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The purpose of my code is to enter a formula into a cell. It pulls a workbook path, name and worksheet from one page and uses it in another cell (in the WS the macro button was clicked) to look up values.
When I run my code I get the error:method 'value' of object 'range' failed
I've looked at other people's problems with this, but found no solution.

```
Sub EquipmentRecord()

Dim CalPath As Variant
Dim CalWB As Variant
Dim CalWS As Variant
Dim FullCalPath As Variant

CalPath = Worksheets("Document Properties").Range("H16")
CalWB = Worksheets("Document Properties").Range("H17")
CalWS = Worksheets("Document Properties").Range("H18")
FullCalPath = "'" & CalPath & "[" & CalWB & "]" & CalWS & ""

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Select

Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = ("=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & FullCalPath & "!R1C1:R100C26,13,FALSE)")

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide sample data for testing any possible solution. From a high level view of your code shouldn't you reference `CalPath = Worksheets("Document Properties").Range("H16").Value2`? Can you also indicate on which line your code errors out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FullCalPath = "'" & CalPath & "[" & CalWB & "]" & CalWS & ""
```

appears to be missing the single quote between the double quotes at the end

```
FullCalPath = "'" & CalPath & "[" & CalWB & "]" & CalWS & "'"
```